# popen, pclose and getdelim functions not included in Turbo C library

Tags: c, popen, pclose

This question is pretty straightforward....

The **pipe functions** (popen, and pclose) and **getdelim functions** are not included in the **Borland Turbo C Libraries** I'm using.

I'm unable to compile any code involving these functions. **MinGw's Library** includes these functions in its **stdio.h**, but MinGw crashes when I use it for compilation on my computer.

So, can I make individual files popen.c, pclose.c and getdelim.c and compile them with the main code on Turbo C? And how should I define and initialize these functions?

I don't know the code for these functions so any code would be very helpful...

Comment: Rather than trying to make them work on Turbo C++, dump that ancient compiler and fix your MinGW. How exactly does it crash? Consider trying a different MinGW distribution (the MSYS2 one, or maybe MinGW-w64).

Comment: When compiling files on MinGw, the antivirus flags the .exe as a virus and denies access to it. I think my copy of MinGw has been compromised..

Comment: Does MYSYS2 and MinGW-w64 work on a 32-bit system?

Comment: *"think my copy of MinGw has been compromised"* That's possible but unlikely. Reinstall it if you want to be extra safe, and add the directory with your programs to the exceptions of the antivirus (AV giving false positives for small self-compiled programs is not new). *"work on a 32-bit system?"* MSYS2 won't work. MinGW-w64 might work. MinGW-w64 is supposed to be better than the original MinGW, but it will probably have the same problem with your AV. You still might need to add your program directory to the exceptions. And consider updating your OS to an x64 one...

Comment: These functions are from POSIX, not standard C.

Comment: And what does POSIX mean??

Comment: Try Clang (LLVM). https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html